# Linux kernel 3 TCP IP tuning

Tags: linux, kernel, tcpip, performance-tuning

I found several resources about tuning linux TCP/IP stack parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf` for high bandwidth connections, but all refer to kernel 2.6.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to tune newer kernels 3.x?

Is this tuning still needed or the new kernels already have "good" defaults?

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you explain the details of the reason why you're trying to tune TCP (i.e. only getting XMbps performance on LAN with a Foo server running `y` daemon etc...).  That said, someone may point out that your reasons for tuning TCP are goofy... but at least you won't be wasting time trying

Answer (score 2):

There are no major differences between 2.6 and 3.0 (like they were with 2.4->2.6). Basically all they did, was to rename 2.6.40 (i think) to 3.0, and started incrementing the second number instead of the third.

All the performance tuning should be more-or-less the same as with 2.6., with possible minor new additions.